# Can a 2 Pass Assembler resolve Nested Forward References

Tags: assembly, microprocessors, forward-reference

I understand that if a symbol is forward referenced, the two pass assembler can solve it. But If there is a nested definition of a symbol e.g.

D EQU A+C

C EQU B+A

B EQU A

A WORD 10

Can this be resolved by a 2 pass Assembler?

Comment: nasm assembles that without complaint, and it's a 2-pass assembler, not multi-pass.  See http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.8 for an example of the kind of thing that *isn't* allowed in NASM, because of it being a 2-pass assembler.

Comment: Another approach is to emulate what an assembler does with paper and pencil. In particular the assembler is building a symbol table (ST) in pass one. At the end of the first pass it knows D <= A+C, C <= B. B <= A, A <= 10. If, at that point you want to resolve D, you go to the ST and see you need to resolve A and C. Then lookup A and gets its value. Lookup C and see it's B. Lookup B and see it's A. All the info needed to resolve D is now in the ST. In fact you can deduce that a two pass assembler will be sufficient for any expression, regardless of nesting.

Comment: as far as i understand it, your problem has nothing to do with how many passes an assembler uses to evaluate expression, rather on how.
Even a single-step assembler could evaluate this, if it uses a map where it stores unresolved symbols, and passes them correctly